# asp.net upload file License file not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i have page to upload files with CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader
when i run this page in my local computer it work correctly
but when i run this page on the domain server it give this error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear, this program is commercial and its need a license to run.

You do not have include the **AjaxUploader.lic** on the bin directory with the **CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader.dll** file.